# How to prove there is no continuous differentiable injective map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$? $n\geq2$.

Tags: calculus, inverse-function-theorem

> How to prove there is no continuous differentiable injective map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R$? $n\geq2$.

This is a problem in entrance to direct PHD of Tsinghua University. I got it from a webfriend. And I know a proof of the following: there is no continuous injective map from $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$. Indeed, suppose $f(\Bbb R^n)$ is an interval $I$, choose the midpint $x_0$ and its inverse $v_0=f^{-1}(x_0)$, then $f: \Bbb R^n\backslash \{v_0\}\to I\backslash \{x_0\}$. Left side is connected, but right side is not. Contradiction!

But in that problem, inverse function theorem should be in used, I do not know how? since $f: \Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, but not $\to \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I think before closing a question as a duplicate of another more general one, careful consideration needs to be given to whether there are certain simplifications possible in the special case. Unless you are omniscient, this may only become apparent once people have been given a chance to answer.

Comment: Nice proof. (Except where is the midpoint of an infinite interval?)

Comment: @Anonymous There is a solution for this special case in the linked question. And it uses IVT.

Comment: @Conifold I don't see it. In any case, I would imagine many people would be discouraged from answering that question in a special case. Just because one person may have done it doesn't mean you'll get the same variety as if people were given a chance to answer the special case. Anyway, I understand that some people think closing questions is a really important thing. Who am I to question that?

Comment: @Anonymous I get where you're coming from, but I think the dupe target is fine. Perhaps xldd might find the answer to their problem in the given question? If they don't, they can edit, or even ask another, more specific question later based on the answers in the dupe target. If you're interested in whether there's a simpler proof for the functional case, then I would encourage you to ask it, and perhaps post a link here as a comment. That could well turn up some interesting answers.